# Background responsive and cover

Tags: html, css

Why when I reduce the window the second div is responsive (Background resize true), the second no ?

```css
.imga {
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url(https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/5638130f9bd1dbafdaabbd88d207439290c1dd206e3d68f201696a5e15b2185756a209.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.imgb {
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8971/firefox_logo.pn);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="imga">

</div>

<div class="imgb">

</div>
```

Thanks you :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sarthakupadhyay I think it's quite clear - he's asking why the first background image isn't scaling but the second one is.

Comment: Yes ; sorry, my english is bad '-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) `cover`:

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

Summing up:
If it's smaller, widen.
If it's bigger, cut it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in behaviour is caused by the fact that the first background image is 450px high and the second one is larger.

If you reduce the width of the window to 478 pixels or less, you will notice that the second image won't resize any further either, because its height is now 450 pixels!